# php array in one line

Tags: php, arrays

How can I put an entire array inside a variable as one big string?

For example

```
$style = array(
    "background" => "red",
    "height" => "100px",
    "width" => "200px"
);
```

I want to put all the styles that I defined inside the array in here:

```
echo '<div style="' .$style. '"></div>';
```

so that the output would be like so:

```
<div style="background:red;height:100px;etc..."></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo '<div style="';
foreach ($style as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ':' . $value . ';';
}
echo '"></div>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
array_walk($style, function(&$item, $key) { $item = "$key: $item"; });
echo join('; ', $style);
```

ps: it will modify the original array